# converting spacy token vectors into text

Tags: python, vector, text, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy to create vectors of a sentence. If the sentence is 'I am working', it gives me a vector of shape (3, 300). Is there any way to get back the text in the sentence using those vectors?

Thank in advance,
Harathi

Comment: can you tell how are you creating the sentence vectors?

Comment: I have some sentences and number of words in each sentence is different. So I am padding all the sentences to a length of 50.  nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')                                      
sent_embedded = np.zeros((50, 300), dtype=np.float32)
tokens = nlp(sentence)
for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        sentence_embedded[i] = token.vector

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can get directly the string from the doc object with .orth_ property, which returns a string representation of the token rather than a SpaCy token object

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
tokenizer = nlp.Defaults.create_tokenizer(nlp)
text = 'I am working'
tokens = [token.orth_ for token in tokenizer(text)]
print(tokens)
['I', 'am', 'working']
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to translate from vectors → words. You can, however, instantiate a second sequence that maps a token sequence to an integer sequence indicating the id of each token in the spacy model's vocabulary.

```
sentence = 'I am working'
document = nlp(sentence)
id_sequence = map(lambda x: x.orth, [token for token in document])
text = map(lambda x: nlp.vocab[x].text, [id for id in id_sequence])
print(text)
['I', 'am', 'working']
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look-up the 'most_similar' words?

```
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    doc1 = nlp("I am working")
    # most_similar words in vocab
    keys, best_rows, scores = nlp.vocab.vectors.most_similar(
        np.asarray([
            doc1.vector,  # the input is 1x1 (x300)
            ]),
        n=20
        )
    # keys is 1xn (x300)
    for key, best_row, score in zip(keys[0, :], best_rows[0, :], scores[0, :]):
        print(f'text: {nlp.vocab[key].text}, score: {score}')  # key: {key}
```

It returned as follows:

```
text: Am, score: 0.8314999938011169
text: aM, score: 0.8314999938011169
text: am, score: 0.8314999938011169
text: AM, score: 0.8314999938011169
text: I, score: 0.8113999962806702
text: i, score: 0.8113999962806702
text: İ, score: 0.8113999962806702
text: 'M, score: 0.7860000133514404
text: 'm, score: 0.7860000133514404
text: MYSELF, score: 0.7333999872207642
text: Myself, score: 0.7333999872207642
text: myself, score: 0.7333999872207642
text: WORKING, score: 0.7249000072479248
text: WOrking, score: 0.7249000072479248
text: working, score: 0.7249000072479248
text: Working, score: 0.7249000072479248
text: knOw, score: 0.7063999772071838
text: know, score: 0.7063999772071838
text: Know, score: 0.7063999772071838
text: KNow, score: 0.7063999772071838
```